# How add OUT parameter to function in Java JDBC (Oracle database)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

SQL function in Oracle Database:

```
FUNCTION init(id in number, code out varchar2) RETURN number;
```

I have SQL (Oracle database) in my java code:

```
private static final String MY_FUNCTION_SQL = "SELECT live.api.init(?,?) FROM DUAL";
```

And my method:

```
void myMethod() throws SQLException {
  try(CallableStatement cs = sdcon.prepareCall(MY_FUNCTION_SQL) {
    cs.setLong(1, _myID);
    cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    ResultSet resultSet = sdInsertTask.executeQuery();
  }
}
```

After `executeQuery()` I got exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06572: Function INIT has out arguments.

Answer (score 0):

change the my_function_sql to

```
private static final String MY_FUNCTION_SQL = "call live.api.init(?,?)";
```

Comment: When I changed from SELECT to CALL, I got exception: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

Comment: could you provide the sql code? to me it looked like this is a stored procedure but if it's a function then the answer of AxelH is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can find the syntax in the javadoc of [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) :

```
{?= call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}
{call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}
```

So you just need to adapt your query, since you need the OUT parameter, use the first syntax

```
{?= call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}
```

Something like :

```
String initQuery = "{?= call live.api.init(?)}";
long _myID = 1L;
try(CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(initQuery)) {
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.setLong(2, _myID);

    ResultSet resultSet = cs.execute();
}
```

Note: you called another `Statement` called `sdInsertTask` in your code... instead of `cs`

You can find a complete example of this [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CallafunctionwithoneOUTparameterthefunctionreturnsaVARCHAR.htm)